# ContentResolver.requestSync() not trigger with low memory on device

Tags: android, memory, android-contentresolver, android-syncadapter

I have a **Sync Adapter** that works almost in all devices. But, when some device has low memory, my **onPerformSync()** it's not called.
Has **ContentResolver** some memory block or something else?
Is there a way to bypass or fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: Having same issue. Tried deleting some apps and it worked flawlessly.